# Need Assistance with Java Morse Code Translator Quickly

Tags: java, morse-code

For my Intro to Java class I'm supposed to create a Morse code translator that can convert both from English to Morse and from Morse to English.  My code works for converting English to Morse, but can't seem to manage to go the other way, from Morse Code to English.  Here is the prompt:

This project involves writing a program to translate Morse Code into English and
English into Morse Code. Your program shall prompt the user to specify the
desired type of translation, input a string of Morse Code characters or English
characters, then display the translated results.
When inputting Morse Code, separate each letter/digit with a single space, and
delimit multiple words with a “|”. For example, - --- | -… . would be the Morse
Code input for the sentence “to be”. Your program only needs to handle a single
sentence and can ignore punctuation symbols.
When inputting English, separate each word with a blank space.

I am wondering what's wrong with my current "Morse code" code.  Please help if you understand what's going wrong, I've spent hours trying to figure this thing out and I've got to this before midnight Pacific Time on 8/26/2015. Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
//Justin Buckley
//8.26.2015
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MorseCodeProject1 {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        char [] English = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };

        String [] Morse = { ".-" , "-..." , "-.-." , "-.." , "." , "..-." , "--." , "...." , ".." , ".---" , "-.-" , ".-.." , "--" , "-." , "---" , ".--." , "--.-" ,  ".-." , "..." , "-" , "..-" , "...-" , ".--" , "-..-" , "-.--" , "--.." , "|" };

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println( "Please enter \"MC\" if you want to translate Morse Code into English, or \"Eng\" if you want to translate from English into Morse Code" );
        String a = input.nextLine();
            if ( a.equalsIgnoreCase("MC"))
            {
                System.out.println( "Please enter a sentence in Morse Code. Separate each letter/digit with a single space and delimit multiple words with a | ." );
                String b = input.nextLine();

                String[] words = b.split("|");
                for (String word: words )
                {
                    String[] characters = word.split(" ");
                    for (String character: characters) 
                    {
                        if (character.isEmpty()) { continue; }
                        for (int m = 0; m < Morse.length; m++)
                        {
                            if (character.equals(Morse[m]))   
                                System.out.print(English[ m ]);    
                        }    
                    }
                    System.out.print(" ");    
                }    
            }

            else if ( a.contains("Eng" ))
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a sentence in English, and separate each word with a blank space.");
                String c = input.nextLine(); 

                c = c.toLowerCase ();

                for ( int x = 0; x < English.length; x++ )
                {
                    for ( int y = 0; y < c.length(); y++ )
                    {
                        if ( English [ x ] == c.charAt ( y ) )

                        System.out.print ( Morse [ x ] + " " );


                    }

                }


            }

            else 
            {
                System.out.println ( "Invalid Input" );

            }

        }



}
```

Comment: where is your code? what you have done? any effort you can show?

Comment: Failure to plan on your behalf does not constitute an emergency on my behalf...

Comment: You gotta give us the code, preferably as an  [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code to convert English to Morse is almost the same as converting Morse to English, what have you tried? Just break the Morse string down into words by looking for the `|` character, then further break each word down into Morse by looking for the blank spaces between morse characters. Then it is as easy as checking each letter one at a time. For example check for D in morse `if(myMorseSequence.equals("-..")){myEnglishLetter = "D";}`

Comment: @sorifiend I don't know how to "look for the | character." Could I use string.split for that and/or could you help me out with some code?

Answer (score 2):

here this code will work for you, you had your english to morse code wrong too i fixed that too

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         char [] English = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };

            String [] Morse = { ".-" , "-..." , "-.-." , "-.." , "." , "..-." , "--." , "...." , ".." , ".---" , "-.-" , ".-.." , "--" , "-." , "---" , ".--." , "--.-" ,  ".-." , "..." , "-" , "..-" , "...-" , ".--" , "-..-" , "-.--" , "--.." , "|" };

            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println( "Please enter \"MC\" if you want to translate Morse Code into English, or \"Eng\" if you want to translate from English into Morse Code" );
            String a = input.nextLine();
                if ( a.equalsIgnoreCase("MC"))
                {
                    System.out.println( "Please enter a sentence in Morse Code. Separate each letter/digit with a single space and delimit multiple words with a | ." );
                    String b = input.nextLine();
                    String[] words = null;
                    if(b.contains("|")){
                     words = b.split("[|]");
                    }else{
                        words = new String[1];
                        words[0] = b;
                    }

                    for (String word: words )
                    {
                        String[] characters = word.split(" ");
                        for(int h = 0;h < characters.length;h++){
                        for(int i = 0;i < Morse.length;i++){
                            if(characters[h].equals(Morse[i])){
                                System.out.print(English[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        }
                        System.out.print(" ");    
                    }    
                }

                else if ( a.contains("Eng" ))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence in English, and separate each word with a blank space.");
                    String c = input.nextLine(); 

                    c = c.toLowerCase ();

                    for ( int x = 0; x < c.length(); x++ )
                    {
                        for ( int y = 0; y < English.length; y++ )
                        {
                            if ( English [ y ] == c.charAt ( x ) )

                            System.out.print ( Morse [ y ] + " " );


                        }

                    }


                }

                else 
                {
                    System.out.println ( "Invalid Input" );

                }

            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I even think I understand what your code does too! I am so grateful :-)

Comment: your welcome, a couple minutes after your deadling but i got it

Comment: nope, still have 3 more hours until it's due. thanks again man

Comment: no problem, i stepped through it with a debugger and the string.split("|") was making the spaces and then i read alittle about regex on wikipedia and it said use [|] with brackets for the split method, just some info though you might find usefull

Comment: a little excercise for me to haha

Comment: you're a lifesaver man

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment: You really really need to do your homework before asking this sort of question.

All the answers can be found in the Java tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

More specifically you want to know how to Manipulating a string: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html

In keeping with the tutorials here is a basic example showing how you can achieve what you want:

```
if ( a.equalsIgnoreCase("MC"))
{
    System.out.println( "Please enter a sentence in Morse Code. Separate each letter/digit with a single space and delimit multiple words with a | ." );
    //Example input string
    String b = ".... . .-.. .-.. --- | .-- --- .-. .-.. -.. | .. -. | -- --- .-. ... ." ;

    //We cant use the split method here because it removes blank spaces, so lets keep it basic:
    //String[] words = b.split("|");
    int letterStart = 0;
    int letterEnd = 0;
    String letter = "";
    while (letterStart < b.length())
    {
        letterEnd = b.indexOf(" ", letterStart);
        //check if end of string has been reached 
        if (letterEnd == -1)
        {
          //grab last morse letter/sequence
          letter = b.substring(letterStart);
        }
        else
        {
          //grab next morse letter/sequence
          letter = b.substring(letterStart, letterEnd);
        }

        //convert each morse sequence to english 
        for (int m = 0; m < Morse.length; m++)
        {
        if (letter.equals("|"))
          {
            //show spaces between words
            System.out.print(" ");
            break;
          }
          else if (letter.equals(Morse[m]))
          {
            //show english letter
            System.out.print(English[m]);
            break;
          }
        }
        if (letterEnd == -1)
        {
        break;
        }
        letterStart = letterEnd+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! appreciate it, you're right, i should've looked around for some more resources before asking. will do that next time.